# Window Server 2012 R2 , IIS , BonCode With Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, iis, server, window, google-cloud-platform

My requirement is host the java application on Google CLoud Virtual Machine Engine. I built the Java Web Application. 
I have create virtual machine by using Google Cloud Engine. The configuration of virtual machine is Window Server 2012 R2 with 150GB. I have configured the IIS server and I am able to see the "It's Work" text from outside in public network. I have read the document on google for access java application by using tomcat connector. I have used the BonCode connector and configured all things. It is working fine with localhost:8080/appName AND localhost/appName on local system. I am also able to access same things out side the virtual machine by using ipAddress:8080/appName AND ipAddress/appName. My issue is that It is working only once in day. I mean when i logged In and logout in application only one time. Again login in application. It give's the ERROR:

> **Generic Connector Communication Error:
>   Please check and adjust your setup:
>   Ensure that Tomcat is running on given host and port.
>   If this is a timeout error consider adjusting IIS timeout by changing executionTimeout attribute in web.config (see manual).**

Comment: Use HttpPlatformHandler and no other third party handlers.

Comment: Please post your BonCodeAJP13.settings and Tomcat server.xml files - there are other parameters that may be relevent eg packetSize, maxThreads etc